# How to convert Cycles materials into LuxCore materials and have textures still applied?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, luxrender-render-engine

My problem is: I have made a model with materials in Cycles render with UV Mapping and Nodes. Now, I want to render through LuxCore, but my model is too bright.. noisy.. and without any of my textures !

I thought I had to ''convert'' my Cycles materials into a LuxCore ones, but I don't know how. I have no button '' Convert Cycles to Luxcore ''.
How can I convert my materials from Cycles render engine to LuxCore render engine?

Comment: When you use a different render engine everything changes, the lights the textures and all settings. There is no single button that just converts everything for you, Just like you have learned Cycles you need to learn Lux, they are different so now you need to go redo all your lights and textures in Lux.

Comment: Ok I understand ! I have to remake my UV Mapping Etc.. like a New project ! Thanks a lot for your answer !! I'm gonna see youtube tutorial... :) Have a good day, thanks !

Comment: No, the UV mapping should still work. Just the materials have to be re-done.

Answer (score 3):

When using a new render engine, many things will change in your scene. There will be an entirely new lighting system, your textures will no longer look correct (although all your UV's will still be good).

The render settings will be completely different, another engine will have different rendering features than Cycles. Render Passes will be handled different, the lighting values will drastically change and may not even work at all. Some render engines (in my case Renderman) requires you to use a separate program called "IT" to render to, you can no longer use your Blender view port to see your renders.

To sum it up:

You will have to redo all your lights, textures, and will have to learn the new settings to best optimize your scene. There is no button to just transfer everything to a new render engine.

Also keep in mind, you may not be able to use any GPU's to render out your scene, I am not sure if this is true for LuxCore but  this is the reason I quit using Renderman.

Comment: LuxCore supports GPU rendering.